# inserting data into partition table

Tags: hive

I am trying to insert huge data from non partition table to partition table.
It was running for 6 hrs then I killed the job.

Please help me to insert the data in less time.

The source `table(master_history)` is having 402133692 records.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;  
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert into table master_partition_tbl partition(logdatetime)
SELECT * FROM master_history;
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update your question with some sample data for `logdatetime` column?, Check how many **unique values** you are having for `logdatetime` data.

Comment: It (logdatetime ) has 1795 unique values.

Comment: try with **distributeby and sortby** clauses `insert into table master_partition_tbl partition(logdatetime)
SELECT * FROM master_history distribute by logdatetime sort by <unique_id..etc>;` also please check out this link once: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/171090/hive-query-with-dynamic-partition-takes-long-time.html

Answer (score 0):

Better if you insert into using STRICT dynamic partition mode and insert it per day instead of 1 huge select like what you are doing.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict;

insert into table partition (logdatetime="20180101 00:00:00")
select *
from source_table
where logdatetime="20180101 00:00:00"
```